# matching different dimension of two matrix using sapply in r?

Tags: r, matrix

let say i have a matrix contains of categorical data

```
X1  X2    X3
low hot  white
high hot black
```

then i want to matching every values to another matrix by their column, here is the matrix.

```
[[1]]
Values        V1        V2
high     0.3076923 0.6315789   
low      0.6923077 0.3684211
[[2]]
Values V1 V2
hot    1  1
[[3]]
Values        V1        V2
black 0.3076923 0.6315789
white 0.6923077 0.3684211
```

X1 will be match to list of matrix [[1]], and the condition is: if they match, we will take the values of V1. for example : the first data is "low" then

```
low --> will compare to a matrix [[1]]
 [[1]]
Values        V1        V2
high     0.3076923 0.6315789   
low      0.6923077 0.3684211
```

we will take 0.6923077. so the final result should be

```
0.6923077 1 0.6923077
0.3076923 1 0.3076923
```

how to use sapply for this case. i know with looping, but i think its not efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your matrix of categorical data (I assume this is a character matrix) is named `mat`, and your list of matrices is named `l`, this should work:

```
# Set up the example data
mat <- matrix(c('low', 'high', 'hot', 'hot', 'white', 'black'), nrow = 2)
l <- list(matrix(c('high', 'low', 0.3076923, 0.6923077, 0.6315789, 0.3684211),
                 nrow = 2),
          matrix(c('hot', 1, 1), nrow = 1),
          matrix(c('black', 'white', 0.3076923, 0.6923077, 0.6315789,
                   0.3684211), nrow = 2))

sapply(1:ncol(mat), function(j){
    tmp_mat <- l[[j]]
    mat[ , j] <<- tmp_mat[match(tmp_mat[ , 1], mat[ , j]), 2]
})

> mat

     [,1]        [,2] [,3]       
[1,] "0.6923077" "1"  "0.6923077"
[2,] "0.3076923" "1"  "0.3076923"
```

Notice this results in a character matrix, since one column of each of the matrices in is a character vector, (and even if not, `mat` is a charcter matrix) resulting in [coercion](https://www.r-bloggers.com/type-conversion-and-you-or-and-r/). This is easily fixed by using `as.numeric(mat)`.

Comment: thank u so much for this help, i really appreciate it @duckmayr

Comment: @Jackshephard If the solution worked for you (i.e. solved your problem), don't forget to accept the answer, and upvote if you found it useful

Comment: seems like i cant vote up, i dont have enough popularity